# в addEventListener не работает submit (После нажатия ENTER на поле формы, выводит в alert Null)

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let myForm = document.querySelector(".myForm");

function calcR(radius) {
  return alert(2 * Math.PI * radius);
}

function calcD(diametr) {
  return Math.PI * diametr;
}

myForm.addEventListener("submit", calcR);
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
  <input class="form-control form-calcR" type="text" placeholder="По радиусу" aria-label="default input example" />
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ты в метод не передаёшь ни одного параметра. Откуда функция должна взять radius? Странно оэидать какой-то другой результат.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В поле ввода я ввожу различные числа, или ты про другое?

Comment: Как функция должна понять, откуда значения брать? Ты передаëшь функцию в качестве обработчика, но не аргументы для неё..

Comment: Кстати, submit - это событие формы, а не инпута (на всякий случай)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо, буду мозговать)

Comment: Обработчик событий принимает (тип событий и само событие (event) - это объект). И если производить с ним математические операции, буте возвращено NaN (not a number) не число.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак Вот именно NaN и выводится :), а как можно провернуть математическую операцию через событие?

Comment: а почему выбрано именно через форму? и отправку событий? почему не сделать через инпут и кнопку?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак я только учусь и решил там попробовать, видимо неверно. Буду пробовать через инпут и кнопку .Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Например вот так**

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const radius = document.querySelector('.input').value;
  alert(2 * Math.PI * radius);
});
```

```html
  <input class="input" type="text">
  <button class="btn">Клац</button>
```

**А если уж очень хочется через форму**

```js
let myForm = document.querySelector(".myForm");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", function () {
  alert(2 * Math.PI * document.querySelector(".form-control").value);
});
```

```html
  <form class="myForm">
    <input class="form-control form-calcR" type="text" placeholder="По радиусу" aria-label="default input example" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо ! :)